# Java Graphics Update/Repaint Graphic

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to work with the Java paint
utility and it's been a bit of a hassle.

I'm trying to do something which I assume is quite basic.
I'm drawing a square Graphic to a JPanel and then trying
to move it using repaint

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class testGui {

   static gui      gc_gui;
   static int      gv_x;
   static int      gv_y;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      gc_gui = new gui();
      gv_x = 50;
      gv_y = 50;

      gc_gui.cv_frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static class gui {

      JFrame    cv_frame;
      content   cv_content;

      public gui() {

         cv_frame = new JFrame();
         cv_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         cv_frame.setTitle("Test GUI");
         cv_frame.setSize(600, 400);
         cv_frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());   

         cv_content = new content();
         cv_content.setBackground(Color.Black);
         cv_content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
         cv_frame.add(cv_content);

         gv_x = 0;
         gv_y = 0;

         cv_content.update();

      }

   }

   public static class content extends JPanel {

      public void paint(Graphics graphic) {
         super.paint(graphic);
         draw(graphic);
      }

      public void update() {
         super.repaint();
      }

      public void draw(Graphics graphic) {
         Graphics2D graphic2D = (Graphics2D) graphic;
         graphic2D.setPaint(Color.Red);
         graphic2D.fillRect(gv_x, gv_y, 100, 100);
      }

   }

}
```

I don't know why the call to the update function isn't doing
anything though.

It draws the square at 50x and 50y, the sets it to 0x and 0y
immediately and then when I call repaint I expected it to
be moved to it's new coordinates although it's still at
50x and 50y.

Why is this?

Comment: You can't do it using the main tread. So you need to a new tread able to move this square.

Comment: Use a Swing Timer or an event listener to move the square.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels why does it only work with an action listener?

Comment: @Trent: it doesn't "only work with an ActionListener". Your code has no delays at all, and so there will be no animation. For animation to occur there must be a change in state with a delay in between. This can be accomplished most easily with a Swing Timer or if you want to do it in response to an event, then some listener such as an ActionListener attached to a JButton or a MouseListener attached to some component.

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand what you mean, thanks a lot for your help. Would you be able to post this as an answer so that I can accept it as the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to use KeyBindings.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

and also.
You need to create a Swing Timer, Thread, or Loop , that manages the frames to be painted. and such

Here is a link for Swing Timers as they are pretty easy to implement:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

A lot of programs I see also have this ( AKA. working with threads.):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

Comment: @trent Its because you dont have anything that is time based.... That means that all your code is executed at one time... Not at certain intervals or periods. Look at the links i posted... As they will explain thoroughly how to implement a delay and why it is needed.